# How to change the order of a list while keeping reference to the original Python

Tags: python, list, alias

I'm creating a sudoku solver and for ease of access I want multiple lists which reference the same elements.
I've created a nested list called grid and then referenced it with a list called rows. Changing rows will change grid. Now I want to create another list that will also "dynamically update together with rows and grid" but that has a different nested structure (cols[i][j] = grid[j][i])

```
rows = grid
cols = [[rows[i][j] for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
blocks = [[rows[l//3*3+k//3][l % 3*3+k % 3]
           for k in range(9)] for l in range(9)]
rows[0][0] = [10] 
cols[1][1] = [5]
```

grid[0][0] will be [10] but now I want cols,blocks[0][0] to be [10] as well and grid,cols,blocks,rows[1][1] to be [5] which doesn't work. Why aren't the elements of the lists: cols and blocks references to the elements of lists rows and grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slice assignment so that you update the lists in place, rather than creating references to new lists.

```
rows[0][0][:] = [10]
cols[1][1][:] = [5]
```